# Text classification: how to assign 1 or more classes to each document?

Tags: machine-learning, r, text-mining

I'm very new to text mining. I am trying to build a classifier which assigns zero, one or more topics to each document of the Reuters 21578 dataset. However, I'm not sure how to make it work using standard R packages. I've looked at a lot of simple online examples using packages such as RTextTools and RWeka, etc. which creates classifier to assign one topic to each document and I'm stuck as I can't directly follow the examples to achieve what I desire. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is multilabel classification.I used mlr package in R ; I followed [this](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/multilabel/index.html#multilabel-classification) link to achieve it.